# Object.keys(data).forEach does not loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I try to to get a value form json object.

```
var data={
"1":[{"departmentID":1,"departmentName":"Adminstration","branchId":1,"branchName":"ABC"}],
"2":[{"departmentID":2,"departmentName":"HR","branchId":2,"branchName":"DEF"}]
};


Object.keys(data).forEach(function(element, key, _array) {                      
    console.log("branchId: "+element+" "+"BranchName : "+data[element][key].branchName)

    for(dept of data[element]) {
            console.log("Department name : "+dept.departmentName)
    }  
});
```

Here output is : **the first result only and throws branchName is undefined exception.**

But if the json object has **multi object**,its working fine.

```
var data={
"1":[{"departmentID":1,"departmentName":"Adminstration","branchId":1,"branchName":"ABC"}],
"2":[{"departmentID":2,"departmentName":"HR","branchId":2,"branchName":"XYZ"},
     {"departmentID":3,"departmentName":"Food","branchId":2,"branchName":"XYZ"}]
}
```

I think, since I'm new to javascript, I couldn't solve. I tried a lot of reference to solve this problem, but I could not. Please try to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> he first result only and throws branchName is undefined exception.

You need to replace

```
data[element][key].branchName
```

with

```
data[element][0].branchName
```

Because

- `element` is the key `"1"`,
- so `data[element]` becomes `[{"departmentID":1,"departmentName":"Adminstration","branchId":1,"branchName":"ABC"}]`,
- `data[element][0]` becomes `{"departmentID":1,"departmentName":"Adminstration","branchId":1,"branchName":"ABC"}`
- finally `data[element][0].branchName` is `"ABC"`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan You are right. OP's data structure can be optimized though.

Comment: thank you so much, But when i print **key**, its printing form 0,1.... So I thought its looping.

Answer (score 1):

You have something mixed with your keys and indexes. 
You can use [**Object.values (ES8 only)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get exact the values and left the keys part. Then iterate over them and make your strings.

```js
const data = {
"1":[{"departmentID":1,"departmentName":"Adminstration","branchId":1,"branchName":"ABC"}],
"2":[{"departmentID":2,"departmentName":"HR","branchId":2,"branchName":"DEF"}]
}


Object.values(data).forEach(function(values) {    
   
   values.forEach(value => {
      console.log(`branchId: ${value.branchId} BranchName: ${value.branchName} Department Name: ${value.departmentName}`);
   });
    
});
```